# Select faces within two cuts/edges

Tags: mesh, faces, edges, selection-tools

I got a subdivided mesh/face where a road should run along. So we have an outer and an inner edge. What I want to do now is delete all these faces that lie within the outer and inner cut/edge. Of course you can do that with circle select but I wonder if there is a faster and more efficient way?

[image: Example]

Comment: It's not possible as you've created tris/ngons by cutting your mesh. Without proper edge flow Blender will not know where edges should be going.

Comment: You could try selecting vertices of the cut (Connected Vertex Path tool with Ctrl while right clicking on the next vertex to select). Once surrounding area of the cut is selected run Select Loop-Inner Region. It should work but not necessarily (depends on the enclosed topology) In this case it's also possible to select by face sides (select all quads), invert selection and in vertex select mode try using Loop-Inner Region.

Comment: If you used Knife Project to make your cut, the faces will all be selected automatically after the cut.  You can just "X" and select "Faces".

Answer (score 2):

If you have a cut in there, you should have separate Mesh Islands.

Hovering your mouse over the island of choice and pressing <kbd>L</kbd> will select the Linked Faces. You can look in the Operator Panel for additional options that will limit the selection, like Seams, for instance.

Alternatively, select just one element and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the linked faces, regardless of where your mouse is at that moment.